# Problemas com múltiplas expressões nas legenda com ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legenda-de-gráfico

Meu gráfico está sendo gerado com a legenda triplicada, ou seja, uma para cada escala. Estou tentando plotar os modelos de estimação para cada linha de tendência na legenda.

Abaixo são apresentados os dados,o código utilizado e a saída com a legenda triplicada:

Os modelos de estimação:

```
eqs<-list(D1 = "italic(hat(Y))==  2.816 ^\"***\" - 0.094 *x^\"***\" *\",\"~~~italic(R)^{2}== 0.4632", 
    D2 = "italic(hat(Y))==  3.3635 ^\"***\" - 0.1202 *x^\"***\" *\",\"~~~italic(R)^{2}== 0.622", 
    D3 = "italic(hat(Y))==  3.7997 ^\"***\" - 0.152 *x^\"***\" *\",\"~~~italic(R)^{2}== 0.7494", 
    D4 = "italic(hat(Y))==  4.0633 ^\"***\" - 0.167 *x^\"***\" *\",\"~~~italic(R)^{2}== 0.7954")
```

Exemplo de código do gráfico:

```
ggplot(data.frame(trat=c(1:4),resp=c(1:4),grupo=c(LETTERS[1:4])),aes(x=trat,y=resp))+
  geom_line(color="black",aes(linetype=grupo,group=grupo))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=grupo,shape=grupo,group=grupo),size=3,color="black")+
  scale_shape_manual("Modelos",labels=parse(text=eqs),values=c(21,22,8,24))+
  scale_fill_manual("Modelos",labels=parse(text=eqs),values=viridis(direction = -1, 4))+
  scale_linetype_manual("Modelos",labels=parse(text=eqs),values=c(1:4))
```

Saída do  gráfico:
[image: Figura 1 - Exemplo de saída do gráfico, com a legenda triplicada]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no uso de `parse` repetidas vezes; `ggplot` não entende que são os mesmos rótulos e separa as chaves de legenda. Passe os rótulos já no formato final:

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- data.frame(trat = 1:4, resp = 1:4, grupo = LETTERS[1:4])

eqs <- list(
  D1 = "italic(hat(Y))==  2.816 ^\"***\" - 0.094 *x^\"***\" *\",\"~~~italic(R)^{2}== 0.4632",
  D2 = "italic(hat(Y))==  3.3635 ^\"***\" - 0.1202 *x^\"***\" *\",\"~~~italic(R)^{2}== 0.622",
  D3 = "italic(hat(Y))==  3.7997 ^\"***\" - 0.152 *x^\"***\" *\",\"~~~italic(R)^{2}== 0.7494",
  D4 = "italic(hat(Y))==  4.0633 ^\"***\" - 0.167 *x^\"***\" *\",\"~~~italic(R)^{2}== 0.7954")

rotulos <- parse(text = eqs)

ggplot(dados, aes(x = trat, y = resp)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = grupo)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = grupo, shape = grupo), size = 3) +
  scale_shape_manual("Modelos", labels = rotulos, values = c(21, 22, 8, 24)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Modelos", labels = rotulos, values = rainbow(4)) +
  scale_linetype_manual("Modelos", labels = rotulos, values = 1:4)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode aproveitar e colocar todos os elementos comuns das legendas em uma lista, reduzindo repetição:

```
rotulos <- list("Modelos", labels = parse(text = eqs))

ggplot(dados, aes(x = trat, y = resp)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = grupo)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = grupo, shape = grupo), size = 3) +
  scale_shape_manual(rotulos, values = c(21,22,8,24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(rotulos, values = rainbow(4)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(rotulos, values = c(1:4))
```

Answer (score -2):

Para evitar que a legenda seja triplicada, basta remover as duas últimas linhas do seu código, que são as que estão adicionando as escalas de cor e forma. Isso deve resolver o problema da legenda triplicada.

O seu código ficaria assim:

```
ggplot(data.frame(trat=c(1:4),resp=c(1:4),grupo=c(LETTERS[1:4])),aes(x=trat,y=resp))+
  geom_line(color="black",aes(linetype=grupo,group=grupo))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=grupo,shape=grupo,group=grupo),size=3,color="black")+
  scale_shape_manual("Modelos",labels=parse(text=eqs),values=c(21,22,8,24))
```

Essa alteração vai fazer com que apenas a escala de linetype seja exibida na legenda, mostrando os modelos de estimação como rótulos.